# MySQL custom order (again) the output of ORDER BY column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

In MySQL, let's say I have a table:

```
 ----------------------
| Price | ProductType |
 ----------------------
8.5     | Foodstuff
8.5     | Mobile
147     | Application
2       | Mobile
8.5     | Electronic
8.5     | Mobile
```

In this situation, if I `ORDER BY Price, ProductType`, it will normally come out as:

```
 ----------------------
| Price | ProductType |
 ----------------------
2       | Mobile
8.5     | Electronic
8.5     | Foodstuff
8.5     | Mobile
8.5     | Mobile
147     | Application
```

Now the problem is:

- Can I customize the `ORDER` by myself? (e.g, Which one comes first, and which one comes second)

For example, how to write a `MySQL Query` to get a result like the following:

```
 ----------------------
| Price | ProductType |
 ----------------------
2       | Mobile
8.5     | Electronic <- 1st in Order
8.5     | Mobile     <- 2nd in Order
8.5     | Mobile     <- ..
8.5     | Foodstuff  <- 3rd in Order
147     | Application
```

Please focus on `8.5` price rows, in this sample (after the first `Order By` on `Price` column), then obviously I want to display: `Electronic` first, then `Mobile` and then `Foodstuff`. Is it possible in `MySQL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `FIELD`

```
ORDER BY Price, FIELD(ProductType,'Electronic','Mobile','Foodstuff')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3601/1)

Comment: Very neat solution, however if data is dynamic then this makes quite complicated queries...

Comment: WOW! THIS IS SO GREAT AND IMPRESSIVE! You are the man JW. ...... Just one thing i want to add a note on this, as i tested, it is not accurate when the column contains `BLANK` values. Also we better define all distinct values in the list we want to use FIELD. Unless, the ordered values will only be listed at the bottom, of the result rows .. and/or likely not accurate. (So, just define all distinct values in the FIELD list)

Comment: what do you mean by blank values? are they `NULL` or just empty string `''`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a third (INT) column in your table for your custom order, name it something smart. Then you can order by that:

```
ORDER BY custom_order
```

If you still want the price to take precedence over the custom order you could do your query:

```
ORDER BY Price, custom_order
```

You just CAN'T make MySQL guess the order you want to arrange by so the alternative solution should be the one suggested by JW. where you specify the actual order in the query. However with a large table and dynamical data I would recommend my solution.

Then hopefully you have a clever administration for your database so you can easily reorder the items the way you want... I have successfully made many db administrations and like to use AJAX and jQuery Sortable for a simple drag-drop reorder.

Comment: I don't think this is a reasonable solution, to apply on huge data pools. Especially at where the existing data structure is very sensitive to be touched or limited.

Comment: Did you downvote because of that? If you want a custom order on a huge table with MANY product types, can you imagine what the query would look like? Not a performance booster I can tell you! At least don't forget to index your ProductType field.